# Change the text in the header of the page when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, header, scroll

I want to change the text in the header of my page (the header sticks to the top) when scrolling down that page.
Each time you pass the bottom of the current div, the text in the header changes again.
This is a prefect example of what I want: [prss.com](http://www.prss.com).
I'm pretty bad with javascript and jQuery, so if annybody has a solution...

Thanks in advance,
Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `.scroll()` event of the `jQuery` to detect the user scroll and then do whatever you want based on the scroll position. The latter one you can get using the `.scrollTop()` function of `jQuery`.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6386w/), which demonstrates the functionality similar to the one you've provided.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking for this so long.